# Transfer file from ftp Server to another ftp server using spring integration ftp support

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration, ftp-server

I am new to Spring and I am currently working on spring integration with ftp support.

- I made a transfer from local directory to a server(filZilla).
- I downloaded the file from server and it was fine.

But I want to find how I can Transfer file from FTP Server to another FTP Server and if it's possible to read file without downloading it from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean fetch a file and send it to another server without writing it to the local file system then, no, that's not currently possible with standard components.

However, you **can** use two `FtpRemoteFileTemplate`s (use the `execute` method) to stream the data from an `InputStream` to an `OutputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

```
FtpRemoteFileTemplate server1;
FtpRemoteFileTemplate server2
server1.get("filetotransfer", new InputStreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void doWithInputStream(final InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        server2.executeWithClient(new ClientCallback<FTPClient, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void doWithClient(final FTPClient client) {
               try (final OutputStream outStream = client.storeFileStream("filedestination");) {
                   IOUtils.copyLarge(stream, outputStream)
               }
        }
    }
});
```